# Bash/FTP: How to create directories and subdirectories via FTP

Tags: bash, ftp

Tried doing this:

```
ftp -nvd server01 <<- END
user user01 password123
mkdir -p /dirA/dirB/dirC/dirD/
```

expected result:

> /dirA/dirB/dirC/dirD/ should be created in server01

actual result:

> -p directory is created in home directory of server01

The problem is "`-p`" is treated as the directory name instead of an option for mkdir command.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The dumb `ftp` client does not support `-p` as an option argument to `mkdir`, but if you require this feature you can use another client which does, e.g. `lftp`.

Comment: Thanks for the advise. Unluckily, the system I'm using does not support lftp client, Maybe I'll just create an mkdir loop for this. Anyway, thanks again for the help.